# is there any better way for reading files?

Tags: python, csv

Every time when i am reading CSv file as list by using this long method, can we simplify this?

1. Creating empty List
2. Reading file row-wise and appending to the list

```
filename = 'mtms_excelExtraction_m_Model_Definition.csv'
Ana_Type = []
Ana_Length = []
Ana_Text = []
Ana_Space = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f)   
    try:
        for row in reader:
            Ana_Type.append(row[0])
            Ana_Length.append(row[1])
            Ana_Text.append(row[2])
            Ana_Space.append(row[3])            
    except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
```

Comment: You could use a [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead.

Comment: you can read it using pandas, then split the dataframe using string methods.

Comment: Are pandas or numpy an option here? They are targetted as processing multi-dimensional arrays (for numpy) or 2D tables (for pandas) with functions that can directly process csv files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good opportunity for you to start using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) and working with DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
```

1-2 (depending on if you count the import) lines of code and you're done!

Answer (score 2):

This one is essentially the numpy way of processing the csv file, without using numpy.
Whether it is better than your original method is close to a matter of taste. It has in common with the numpy or Pandas method the fact of loading the whole file in memory and than transposing it into lists:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f)   
    tmp = list(reader)
Ana_Type, Ana_Length, Ana_Text, Ana_Space = [[tmp[i][j] for i in range(len(tmp))]
                                             for j in range(len(tmp[0]))]
```

It uses less code, and build arrays with comprehensions instead of repeated appends, but more memory (as would numpy or pandas).

Depending on how you later process the data, numpy or Pandas could be a nice option. Because IMHO using them only to load a csv file into list is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'rt') as f:  
    data = list(csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=["Type", "Length", "Text", "Space"]))

print(data)
```

This will give you a single `list` of `dict` objects, one per row.

Answer (score 1):

This could be useful:

```
import numpy as np
# read the rows with Numpy
rows = np.genfromtxt('data.csv',dtype='str',delimiter=';')
# call numpy.transpose to convert the rows to columns
cols = np.transpose(rows)

# get the stuff as lists
Ana_Type = list(cols[0])
Ana_Length = list(cols[1])
Ana_Text = list(cols[2])
Ana_Space = list(cols[0])
```

Edit : note that the first element will be the name of the columns (example with test data):

```
['Date', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05', '2020-03-06']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
with open(filename, mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        for k,v in row.items():
            d[k].append(v)
```

next

```
d.keys()
dict_keys(['Ana_Type', 'Ana_Length', 'Ana_Text', 'Ana_Space'])
```

next

```
d.get('Ana_Type')
['bla','bla1','df','ccc']
```

Answer (score 1):

The repetitive calls to `list.append` can be avoided by reading the csv and using the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function to transpose the rows.

```py
import io, csv

# Create an example file
buf = io.StringIO('type1,length1,text1,space1\ntype2,length2,text2,space2\ntype3,length3,text3,space3')

reader = csv.reader(buf)
# Uncomment the next line if there is a header row
# next(reader)

Ana_Types, Ana_Length, Ana_Text, Ana_Space = zip(*reader)

print(Ana_Types)
('type1', 'type2', 'type3')
print(Ana_Length)
('length1', 'length2', 'length3')
...
```

If you need lists rather than tuples you can use a list or generator  comprehension to convert them:

```
Ana_Types, Ana_Length, Ana_Text, Ana_Space = [list(x) for x in zip(*reader)]
```