# Python 3 ~ How to obtain same result using CSV module

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, file

I have this in my code:

```
with file:

csv = csv.reader(file,delimiter=",")



df = pd.read_csv(argv[1])
data = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'name'].to_numpy().tolist()
data.insert(0, df["name"].tolist())
```

and it `output` result is  this when i run `print(data)`:

```
[['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 8, 3], [4, 1, 5], [3, 2, 5]]
```

I would love to know how i can obtain this same result using CSV module or for loops

content:

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there content of this CSV file?

Comment: Done , in the original code it excludes the header (name,AGATC,AATG,TATC)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63057812/5320906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvreader) # skip headers
    names = []
    data = []
    for row in csvreader:
        names.append(row[0])
        data.append(list(map(int, row[1:])))

print([names] + data)
```

Prints:

```
[['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 8, 3], [4, 1, 5], [3, 2, 5]]
```

---

EDIT:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvreader) # skip headers
    names = []
    data = []
    for row in csvreader:
        names.append(row[0])
        data.append(list(map(int, row[1:])))

all_data = [names] + data

print(all_data[0])
print(all_data[1])
```

Prints:

```
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
[2, 8, 3]
```

Comment: how to merge both names and data so that when i write print data[0] it outputs all the names and data[1] outputs [2, 8, 3] and so on 

i tried column.append(names+data) but it made one chunk of data not a list

Answer (score 1):

Would that work for you?

```
import csv
from sys import argv

def csv_to_list_of_lists(csv_file):
    
    with open(csv_file) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

        number_of_columns = len(next(reader))#Notice how next() enables to skip the header row
        
        data = [[] for x in range(number_of_columns)] 
        
        for index, line in enumerate(reader):
            data[0].append(line[0])
            values = [int(x) for x in line[1:]]
            data[index+1] = values

    return data

output = csv_to_list_of_lists(argv[1])
print(output)
```

result:

```
[['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 8, 3], [4, 1, 5], [3, 2, 5]]
```

Comment: i would like it to ouput [['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 8, 3], [4, 1, 5], [3, 2, 5]] not [['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], ['2', '4', '3'], ['8', '1', '2'], ['3', '5', '5']] (different numbers)